# Visual studio code: "matplotlib" is not accessed Pylance

Tags: python, visual-studio, matplotlib, anaconda

I get the error in the title when I try to import matplotlib. Please I have been searching for 3 hours and still no solution.I've tried `source activate base` changing the interpreter, I have updated to latest matplotlib. and I have tried `echo "backend : TkAgg" > ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc` but none of these works. But `numpy` works but for some reason `matplotlib` does not. any help is appreciated.

terminal message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MacBook/python/code/stats.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
(base) MacBook-Air:~ MacBook$
```

My matplotlib version:
[image]

On another note: when trying to import matplotlib I see a `matplotlib_inline` but not matplotlib on VS CODE

Comment: try changing your python interpreter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since You already installed `matplotlib` and since I had a similar problem, heres what I did:

1.) change your python interpreter: In VSCODE there's usually a "recommended" interpreter that they will recommend, try that one. If that dosen't  work try to use the interpreter with "conda" in the name.

2.) This is the most important but overlooked step: RESTART your VS code to see the changes. bring up the `command palate` via `cmd + shift + p`, then type in "reload" and a "reload window" should pop up, click on it to reload.

3.) once reloaded you should be able to `import matplotlib` now.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting vsCode after a library installation is underrated. it solved my problem with  accesssing urllib3 after an installation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).